# How to set environment variable in KDE desktop file

Tags: kde, plasma5, desktop-file

I need to set `GDK_BACKEND=x11` prior to launching Eclipse, because of https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=389495.

I tried the following in the .desktop file:

```
Exec=GDK_BACKEND=x11 /home/glodt/Software/eclipse-4.7/eclipse
Exec=env GDK_BACKEND=x11 /home/glodt/Software/eclipse-4.7/eclipse
Exec=export GDK_BACKEND=x11; /home/glodt/Software/eclipse-4.7/eclipse
```

but none of them yield the expected result.

When I launch Eclipse from the command-line like this it works:

```
GDK_BACKEND=x11 /home/glodt/Software/eclipse-4.7/eclipse
```

How can I set this environment variable in the desktop file ?

Comment: You could try `Exec=/usr/bin/env GDK_BACKEND=x11 home/glodt/Software/eclipse-4.7/eclipse`, but since I don't run KDE I can't really test it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It mkes no differences unfortunaltely.

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, as @Kusalananda mentioned in the comments:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env VAR=value command
```

Manpage:

> ```
> env - run a program in a modified environment
> env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Exec=bash -c "GDK_BACKEND=x11 /home/glodt/Software/eclipse-4.7/eclipse"
Terminal=true
```

you can also try `sh`

```
Exec=sh -c "GDK_BACKEND=x11 /home/glodt/Software/eclipse-4.7/eclipse"
Terminal=true
```

I'm not sure whether you need `Terminal=true`